# Error with varchar(max) column when using net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver

Tags: sql, solr, jdbc

I have a MS SQL database running (MS SQL 2005) and am connecting to it via the net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.

The query works fine for all the columns except one that is a varchar(max).  Any ideas how to get around this issues?

I am using the jdbc driver to run a data index into a SOLR implementation.

(I do not control the database, so the first prize solution would be where I can tweak the SQL command to get the desired results)

Thanks

Comment: select 
 b.Title 
 , Permalink
 , Subject
 , PlainText
 , Tags
 , convert(nvarchar(50), m.CreationDate, 127) as MessageCreationDate
 , convert(nvarchar(50), m.LastDateUPdated, 127) as MessageLastDateUpdated
 , m.messageid
FROM blog b (NOLOCK)
inner join message m (NOLOCK)
on b.BlogId = m.BlogId
where b.deleted = 0 and m.deleted = 0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found what looks to be a answer. In setting up the driver for the connection to SQL server I did not specify useLobs=false.  I am a bit worried about what this will mean for performance, but at least for now it works.

```
<dataSource
    driver="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server/database;useLOBs=false" 
    user="user" 
    password="password" />
```

Comment: JDBC driver settings always seem very random to me, great simple example!

Comment: Had the same problem, and this solution worked for me :). However I was interested in knowing why this worked and there is a great description at their site : http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html , search for useLOBs if you want to know why :)

Comment: Same issue, well similar, MS SQL Azure, JDBC, SPRING Boot JPA.  No value being returned, but based on this, changed from varchar(max) to varchar(4000) and got the value.  Weird, no exception was being generated.  Now on to more research, as Need VarChar (max) - I believe

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with connecting to MS SQL 2K3.  The useLOBs=false did not work for me, but changing the SELECT to `CAST(Name AS varchar(255))'Name'` worked for me.